# Recovering Shared Files

Tags: data-recovery

I was sent a folder through Dropbox that is supposed to contain several deleted files. My job is to restore them. The person who sent them to me can click the trashcan icon and retrieve these files. However, when I go to do so, it continues to say that the folder is empty. Is there a way to fix this or are deleted files not transferred when you share a file?

Answer (score 2):

The folder you see in dropbox, is initially created on a users computer. On that machine it has a relation to the trashcan or recycle bin (on that same machine). Hence that this user can  retrieve these files from the trashcan (unless it is emptied).

When that folder was initially shared with files in it, you could access those files because they were synced to dropbox. as soon as the user deleted those files from his folder, dropbox will sync the folder again, and remove those files from it. the same thing basically happens on your computer, but in your case the files are not moved to the recycle bin, but they are moved to the dropbox cache folder. You have an option to restore them from there, but they are not stored there forever.

If the folder was shared via dropbox after the files had been deleted, then dropbox only has the empty folder, and it will never know about any files inside it, so there is also no option to restore those files.